# bpm webMethods - error when debugging

Tags: business-process-management, webmethods

I am using webMethods 8.2 . I have created a very simple BPM process with just start and end event. When I try to debug it by clicking "Debug Selected Process" I get the error : "The process engine did not return a process instance ID" . 
Please help how to get past this error.Thank you.

Maria Tamas

Comment: And you published the process to IS?